# vuetify apply text variant to other component than alert

Tags: vuetify.js

In vuetify, `<v-alert />` component has a [`text`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-alert/#props-text) variant.

I'd like to apply it to my `v-expansion-panel` component, how can I do that?

[image]

```
<v-alert type="warning" text>
  My alert info
</v-alert>

<v-expansion-panels >
  <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-header color="warning" text>
      <v-icon>mdi-alert</v-icon>
      My expansion panel info
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panel-content color="warning" text>
      Content
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background and text variant for styling within your application through a class, e.g. `<div class="red">` or `<span class="red--text">`
refrence: [Vuetify classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#classes)

```js
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),

    })
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.24.0/axios.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>




     <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-app>
          <v-container>
            <v-card elevation="1">
             <v-expansion-panels >
  <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-header class="orange lighten-5 orange--text" text>
      <v-icon class="orange lighten-5 orange--text">mdi-alert</v-icon>
      My expansion panel info
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panel-content class="orange lighten-5 orange--text" text>
      Content
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
            </v-card>
          </v-container>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    </div>
```